# ElasticSearch term aggregation on date fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm sending this request to ES:

```
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "followUpActivity.metainfo.metainfos.date1" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "metainfos.date1",
        "missing" : "2016-07-20T13:59:06.208Z",
        "order" : {
          "_count" : "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the result:

```
{
  "took":1,
  "timed_out":false,
  "_shards":{
    "total":1,
    "successful":1,
    "failed":0
  },
  "hits":{
    "total":5,
    "max_score":1.0,
    "hits":[
      {
        "_index":"living_v1",
        "_type":"fuas",
        "_id":"4a4137ec-48fe-11e6-9f47-30b5c2122322",
        "_score":1.0,
        "_routing":"living_team",
        "_source":{
          "user":"living_team",
          "timestamp":"2016-07-13T15:04:15.548Z",
          "metainfos":{
            "string1":[
              "s1",
              "s2"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index":"living_v1",
        "_type":"fuas",
        "_id":"4d526f8d-48fe-11e6-9f47-30b5c2122322",
        "_score":1.0,
        "_routing":"living_team",
        "_source":{
          "user":"living_team",
          "timestamp":"2016-07-13T15:37:24.471Z",
          "metainfos":{
            "string1":[
              "s1",
              "s2"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index":"living_v1",
        "_type":"fuas",
        "_id":"89fc1180-48fe-11e6-9f47-30b5c2122322",
        "_score":1.0,
        "_routing":"living_team",
        "_source":{
          "user":"living_team",
          "timestamp":"2016-07-13T13:43:18.566Z",
          "metainfos":{
            "string1":[
              "s3"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index":"living_v1",
        "_type":"fuas",
        "_id":"7168393b-4daf-11e6-83ba-30b5c2122322",
        "_score":1.0,
        "_routing":"living_team",
        "_source":{
          "user":"living_team",
          "timestamp":"2016-07-19T14:04:14.175Z",
          "metainfos":{
            "date1_ldate":[
              "2016-07-19T12:59:55.442Z"   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index":"living_v1",
        "_type":"fuas",
        "_id":"7af3f44f-48fe-11e6-9f47-30b5c2122322",
        "_score":1.0,
        "_routing":"living_team",
        "_source":{
          "user":"living_team",
          "timestamp":"2016-07-13T14:18:49.328Z",
          "metainfos":{
            "string1":[
              "s2"
            ],
            "num1":[
              12.0,
              13.0
            ],
            "date1_ldate":[
              "2016-07-19T13:04:55.467Z",    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
              "2016-07-20T12:44:32.116Z"     <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations":{
    "followUpActivity.metainfo.metainfos.date1":{
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
      "sum_other_doc_count":0,
      "buckets":[

      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see `metainfos.date1_ldate` is informed on two documents, however buckets result is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The field name is `date1_ldate` not `date1`. So, you need `"terms" : { "field" : "metainfos.date1_ldate"`.

Comment: Sorry!! As you can guess, I'm building this request using Java API. After having changed my misspelling, I've realised ES Java API returns a `LongTerms` instead of a some kind of `DateTerms`. Do you know how should I deal with this `LongTerms` aggregation in order to get my dates?

Comment: Hm... internally ES stores the dates as timestamps meaning a long numeric value. From looking at [the source code of `LongTerms`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/bucket/terms/LongTerms.java#L33) I see the intention was to use it as you see it - for date fields. So this is the expected behavior. I suggest casting to `java.util.Date` with [one of the constructors that can receive a `long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date(long)).

Comment: I see. Mmm, is there some way to check if the long bucket value source is a date or a long?

Comment: I'm not following. You should be able to use Date casting for those aggregations you know for sure it will return dates (or `long` timestamps which can be casted to `Date`).